# Public certificate of Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, x509certificate, jwt, trust

As part of POC, I want my existing web api, programmatically - to verify the signature of JWT access tokens to validate the authenticity of the token issued by demo AAD so that it can be trusted by my webapi app., to do the verification I need to have .cer/public certificate of my demo AAD.
How to get .cer file of AAD to do signature verification?

Comment: You don't need the certificate to validate signature. You delegate received token validation to AAD/MS Graph. Take a look at this complete tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/calling-an-aspnet-core-web-api-from-a-wpf-application-using-azure-ad-v2/

Comment: @Crypt32, But as per my business requirement, client application need AAD's(issuer) public certificate to validate its access token signature. How to get public certificate of Azure AD?

Comment: Some update would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your app platform, you should use middleware libraries. You can take a look at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries. You shouldn't write your own validation code. It won't be any better than industry standard libraries. Pick appropriate module/middleware and use it in your project instead.

Comment: @prkat If you want to validate AAD token signature, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature